# parameters of ARMA process

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, identifiability

Let $z_{t}$ be ARMA(1,1) process. 
$$
z_{t+1} = \phi z_{t} + \theta\varepsilon_{t} + \varepsilon_{t+1}
$$

In order to have a stationary process we must have $|\phi| < 1$. This is clear. The auto-correlation function is for $\theta : = \theta$ and $\theta : = \frac{1}{\theta}$ is unchangeable, as discussed here [ARMA model with MA coefficient greater than 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434672/arma-model-with-ma-coefficient-greater-than-1/434804#434804)

Though, the auto-covariance function (and, consequently, the variance) does depend on $\theta$, i.e., for example for $\tau =0, 1$:
$$
\gamma(0) = \sigma^2 \frac{1 + 2\phi\theta + \theta^2}{1 - \phi^2}
$$
and
$$
\gamma(1) = \sigma^2 \frac{(\phi + \theta)(1 + \phi\theta)}{1 - \phi^2}
$$

The question: why do we use then  condition $|\theta| < 1$? Do we need it in some computational algorithms which use the auto-correlation function?

Comment: Hi.  Read example 3 on page 8 of this. https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/de-jong.8/note2.pdf.

Comment: Dear @mlofton, I see... therefore, is there any way to estimate the variance of noise to non-invertible process?

Comment: Like I said in the other thread, you'd have to understand the python code (assuming it's correct ) and then tweak it to implement the opposite constraint. Not easy but , as far as I know, the only way. Or, convert arima to state space, run the KF algorithm ( first use prediction error decomp to get variances ) and hope that the $\theta$ and $\phi$ estimates satisfy the constraints.